# New Hydraulic hoses sealed

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake, 105, hydraulic

I have a new complete set of "Shimano" 105 hydraulic calipers and brake/shifters for drops. The hoses are fitted to the calipers the other end of the hoses have the barbs fitted but they appear to be sealed with what looks like wax or a thin plastic film. Should I puncture it or will it be pierced when I fit them to the brake/shifters?

Item came from Aliexpress.

Comment: I'd suspect it is to keep junk out during packing and handling.   If you punctured the seal, the loose parts would still be in the brake fluid and could cause issues, so I'd remove the seal completely once you're ready.   Guessing, so not posted as an answer.

Comment: This is my guess too though I would go for removal rather than puncture. This set came via AliExpress and I am guessing it is pre-assembled and tested for a specific manufacturer and then the hoses are disconnected from the levers and something like clingfilm is placed over the end of the barb for shipping. I am waiting for some other parts so I will give a definitive answer when I actually assemble everything.

Comment: The official boxed set comes like this. I'll show you a picture later. The actual instructions will be on si.shimano.com @mt_subnet

Comment: Would be handy to have the part number of the box-set as I can't access any instructions without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of views and the lack of answers has allowed me to determine that what I have has been pre-assembled and tested for a specific manufacturer. I am guessing that the hoses were disconnected from the levers and something like clingfilm is placed over the end of the barb for shipping, this material is not visible with the naked eye but it seems the only explanation.
This set came via AliExpress and was cheaper than buying the two shift/brake levers, the hoses and calipers simply came as a free bonus perfect for a conversion from straights to drops. I am waiting for some other parts so I will give a definitive answer when I actually assemble everything.
Thanks for all who looked and those made suggestions.
My supposition was correct and removal was tricky, using needle and Stanley blade.

Comment: Consider Shimano has a network of official distributors, and Aliexpress will guaranteed not be on that list even if the product is labelled Shimano.  There's a good chance this is not authentic Shimano; that's a detail worth including int he question.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the hoses need cutting down and a new barb fitting (supplied in the box), making the question redundant. The olive is in the shifter body already.

If you don't need to cut down the hose, you don't need to remove the seal. Something in the shifter body pops it or it is displaced by pressure. Things Shimano want you to remove are generally 1. very obvious (yellow) and 2. easy to remove.